# Create CSV file and save to Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

Is it possible to create a CSV file and store, update it on AppEngine Blobstore. Also would it be possible to email this blobstore CSV file as attachment? If yes, are are any sample docs available to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes you can [write data to blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore), including CSV data (which is just text).
2. You can also [read data from blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileReadChannel.html), and [create mail with attachment](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html#Multi_Part_Messages).

**Update:**

You can append to the file until it's finally closed - meaning you can append to it via a series of requests. But once `closeFinally()` is called, it becomes immutable - you can not append to it or change contents.

Comment: While those answers are great, few questions are still left. Is it possible to update a blobstore file?

Comment: For "Update a file" you can overwrite a file in Google Storage - so depending on how your app works it might be possible for you to do something. You'd need to protect against race conditions so it might get tricky, but it's technically possible.

Comment: For now i am just inserting data into Google Spreadsheet via API call. Wish one can transfer data from Datastore to Cloud MySQL and run queries over there. It is getting really hard to segment data, which otherwise take minutes, now takes 1-2 hours for setting up mapreduce jobs, upload app, fixing bugs and stuff.

Comment: Why are you using Google Spreadsheet? I thought your case was generating CSV file and sending it as a mail attachment?