# Appengine blobstore as filesystem restrictions and questions

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blobstore

In the next couple of days I have to start writing some report generation functions. I need the write call to be atomic and to let me know if something failed while storing.

A experimental feature on appengine allows to use the blobstore as a filesystem.
(https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview).

I have the following questions:

1) Using the file service api as shown, is there any extra charges being applied? Is the only quota being effected is amount of data in Blobstore?

2) At which point is the data actually written? I take it in this example out.close()?

3) After you use closeFinally() on the write channel, can you re-open it and append data? 
(No, answer is in [Create CSV file and save to Blobstore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671252/create-csv-file-and-save-to-blobstore))

4) If the write channel is open, can you still read the data? Is it required to finalize?

5) Is the write operation atomic? Ie, while writing to the the write channel is it possible for something to fail, and end up with missing data?

6) Where is this data being stored while the write channel isn't finalized?

7) Does the data in the write channel ever expire if not finalized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a limitation of the amount of writes (or data written) per day, it is undocumented AFAIK but is pretty high. There are no extra changes.
2. The file is transfer to the blobstore on closeFinally.
3. The blobstore is immutable. You cannot append blobs.
4. You can read only from a blob that was finalized.
5. Yes, if you don't finalize the file it will get lost completely.
6. In the memory of the instance AFAICT.
7. Yes, see #5

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the documentation it mentioned that you can close a write channel, re-open it and  continue writing, even across requests. Since multiple request's won't go to the same instance, do you know how this is handled too?

Comment: I really don't say where it keep the blob before finalizing it, I notice that writing very big blobs will blow up my instance memory (but maybe it got something todo with the data it self) so I figured that the instance memory is the place they keep it. But then again, maybe they keep the data somewhere else where all instance can access it.

Comment: Cool. Regarding #5, the file system docs state that it may be possible. You can use a sequence key to prevent this from happening. Although this will be kind of hard to implement if you use multiple instances to generate different parts of a report and they all write to the same location.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileWriteChannel